# Add class if error and re-run class if new error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to add a class "shake" in my form when I have an error in vuejs.

```
<el-form :class="{ 'anim-shake': has_error } ref="form" :label-width="0" label-position="top" @keyup.enter.native="login" method="post" label-width="120px">
  <el-form-item>
    <el-input placeholder="Adresse e-mail" id="email" type="email" v-model="email" required></el-input>
  </el-form-item>
  <el-form-item class="login__password">
    <el-input placeholder="Entrez votre mot de passe" id="password" v-model="password" required show-password></el-input>
  </el-form-item>
  <el-form-item>
    <el-button type="primary" plain @click.prevent="login" class="btn btn-default">Connexion</el-button>
</el-form-item>
```

I use : `:class="{ 'anim-shake': has_error }`

The data `has_error` becomes `true` when there is an error in my form. And the shake class is added.

The shake class makes the block move.

As the class is already added and the data `has_error` is `true`, when I submit the form again with an error, the animation no longer works.

To do this, the class should be removed and added to each form submit, but I don't know how.

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: When you want the block to shake again, you can set the error to `false`, then on next tick, you set it back to `true`: `this.has_error = false;this.$nextTick(() => this.has_error = true);`

Comment: In your `login` method you can reset `has_error` before any other actions. Then it will check form fields and set `has_error` to true again, if needed